# Compute the value of the integral $\int ^{\infty}_0 \frac{1}{1+2ax+x^2} dx $

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Compute the value of the integral $$\int ^{\infty}_0 \frac{1}{1+2ax+x^2} dx $$
Differentiating by $a$ didn't work for me, and I'm all out of ideas..

Comment: $x^2 + 2ax + 1 = (x + a)^2  -a^2 + 1 = (x + a)^2 - (a^2 - 1)$.

Comment: Just as M. Vinay wrote, complete the square and change variable.

Comment: Translate $x$ to get rid of the term $2ax$. You will find a known pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you complete the square then the integral becomes, 
$$\int ^{\infty}_0 \frac{1}{1+2ax+x^2} dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(x+a)^2+1-a^2}$$

For $a=1$ the solution is obvious.

For $a \gt 1$, this will lead to $$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(x+a)^2-(\sqrt{a^2-1})^2}$$ which can be evaluated.

For $a \lt 1$, the integral will turn out to be $$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(x+a)^2+(\sqrt{1-a^2})^2}$$ which also can be evaluated.

Answer (score 4):

Assume for definiteness that $0\leq a<1$. Then, after the change of variables $x=-a+\sqrt{1-a^2}\tan t$ the integral transforms into
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\int_{\arctan\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}}^{\pi/2} dt=
\frac{\arccos a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}.$$
For $a>1$, the appropriate change of variables would be $x=-a+\sqrt{a^2-1}\coth t$, with the final result given by $\displaystyle \frac{\operatorname{arccosh} a}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}$.